How do I use Bootstrap for making my website?
I don't know how to use Bootstrap to in the html.
I tried to center the code and also set the color by using Bootstrap. For Example:
I tried a lot but this is not working, I m new to coding, please help me with this
<html lang="en">
<head>
[text](https://stackoverflow.com)    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Link to external CSS file. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assign1.css">
    <title>JavaScript Assignment 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Header starts with title -->
        <header>
            <h2 class="text-center flow">Assignment 1 - HTML, CSS and Bootstrap</h2>
            <div class="box anime2">
                <P>Name: Bhargav Patel <br>
                Student ID: 000882786</p>
            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- Header ends here -->

        <!-- Navigation starts here -->
        <nav>
            <!-- nav-link disabled used to disable current page link -->
            <p class="nav-link disabled"><a href="./index.html">Main Page</a></p>
            <p class="space"><a href="./page2.html">Page 2</a></p>
        </nav>
        <!-- Navigation ends here -->

<main>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <a href="https://ozofe.com/rupi-kaur/you-are-too-late/"> 
                <img src="never_too_late.jpg" alt="author" title="Never Too Late" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail">
            </a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-6">
            <!--Poem content and Reference: https://ozofe.com/rupi-kaur/you-are-too-late/ -->
            <div class="text-center">
                <h4>YOU ARE TOO LATE</h4>
                <p class="fs-5">sometimes <br>
                the apology <br>
                never comes <br>
                when it is wanted <br>
                and when it comes <br>
                it is neither wanted <br>
                nor needed <br>
                - rupi kaur</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>


Did you import the bootstrap library? Like so,

One way of using grid system and Bootstrap css styling is to add this CDN link in your HTML head
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">

If you plan to use dropdown and navbars you need to add these CDNs as well At the end of your HTML page (end of body).

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

For more détails pls check link
